Does hill time count faster in KoTH (King of The Hill) if there are more than one person on the hill?
When playing KoTH (King of The Hill) in Halo Infinite, does the hill time count faster if there's more than one person on the hill?
Or does the hill time count the same regardless of how many people are actively on the hill?

No.
The hill capture time in Halo: Infinite is 35 seconds, regardless of how many players of the same team occupy the hill.
However, it can be advantageous and disadvantageous to have more than one player on the hill at different times. For example, having multiple players on the hill while early in a capture attempt will only invite more teammates getting damaged via splash damage from grenades and rockets. It should be the task of other teammates to watch entry points and prevent entry of opponents to the general area. When a hill is almost done being captured, it's a generally good strategy for everyone to stack up on the hill, to try and prevent opponents from contesting the hill.

I recall Halo 3 being the same. Was it?

It is, other than it using the old scoring system from games before Infinite. You get 1 point for every ~1 second you control a hill, regardless of how many players occupy the hill.

No, the hill time counts the same regardless of how many people are on the hill. The time required to capture and hold the hill remains the same whether there is one player or multiple players on it.
But having multiple players on the hill is to better defend against opponents, rather than accelerating the hill's capture time.
